# Extjs 4.2: limiting the value

Tags: extjs

I have a pop-up window where the user will input an integer in the textfield. After they click the save button, it will then be saved in the database then will be displayed in a grid..

here's an example

staytime
10
5
10
etc..

Users are allowed to input multiple entries, but I want to limit the value of the staytime until 30. If the sum of the stay time, exceeded 30, it will be an error. I tried to put a hidden textfield where the value of it will be set as the staytime.

I am lost. Please help.

Comment: I'm Not sure what is your exact problem, do you have trouble with saving value on server or validating user input of "staytime" or refreshing grid view after save. Could you be more precise and specific about problem that troubles you.

Comment: Sorry, I want to limit the input of the user of staytime to 30. If the sum of all the staytime the user inputed exceeded 30, it will return as error.

Answer (score 1):

For custom user validation on text fields you can use [Ext.form.field.Text.validator](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator) configuration property.

Basically all you have to do is splitting user input value and if add up value exceed 30 you should return error message or return `true` if value is correct, something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    // all other configuration options
    validator: function(userInput) {

        // Make sure your user input is formatted the way you want it ...

        var values = userInput.split(" ");
        var sum = 0;

        // Loop trough values to calculate sum ...

        return (sum <= 30) ? true : 'Your error message goes here';
    }
}
```